# What is the best way to call one @RequestMapping method from another in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request

I have 3 methods in a controller, looking something like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value="export-data")
public ExcelView exportData(String urlForData, String paramToPass) {
    List<Data> data; //WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE?
    return new ExcelView(data);
}

@RequestMapping(value="get-data-1")
public List<Data> getData1(String param) {
    //return the data based on param
}

@RequestMapping(value="get-data-2")
public List<Data> getData2(String param) {
    //return the data based on param
}
```

The value for `urlForData` will be either `get-data-1` or `get-data-2`. And I'll need to call the specified method with the given `paramToPass`.

Is there a way to call the methods via Spring (versus just doing a String equality check)? Notice that this is not a redirect as I want to remain in the `exportData` method (versus giving up control to the other methods).

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why are you looking for a different solution than a `String` equality check? (A solution, by the way, which will be much faster than any other if invoked within `exportData`.)

Comment: could you elaborate your problem with requests examples and expected results (or code paths?)?

Comment: I want to avoid the `String` equality check because I want to make the method generic and extendable (i.e. don't need to add back end code if you want to call another `getData3` method from the front end).